# ¿Cómo puedo evitar hacer un update si hay valores que estan undefined? (Angular / Node)

Tags: nodejs, angular4

Buenas!
Cómo se suele manejar programáticamente esto?

Tengo 4 campos: nombre, apellido, identificación (no ID), edad. Hay una vista para editar estos valores pero el usuario puede elegir editar sólo el nombre.

¿Cómo hago para que el resto de los valores, que al estar undefined, no se pasen a al insert desde angular?

En angular yo paso un objecto JSON con los valores a updatear y en una vista con sólo dos campos hice un if que se ejecuta si valor 1 está undefined y el otro no, si el valor 2 esta undefined y el otro no o si ambos no están undefined. El problema es que es poco práctico y, si mis cálculos no fallan, ahora debería hacer 4^2 posibilidades por este caso.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Gracias

---

### Solución:

Después de buscar un poco encontré algo que sirve para **ES6**:

```
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');
```

Lo que hace es borrar los objetos que tenga un valor undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa seria  usar las funciones propias de angular `angular.isDefined` o `angular.isNotDefined`

```js
var variable = undefined;

console.log(angular.isDefined(variable));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```